# bootstrap menu repeated on several html static web pages

Tags: css, menu, static, zurb-foundation

I'm building a simple static website with Foundation.

I'm wondering how I can code the menu navigation of site without repeating the menu code on each html page (so it is easier to maintain in the future)? I could do a Javascript include with the menu but I wouldn't be able to change the navigation class appearance for each menu item (ex.: highlight "About Us").

Or is there a tool out there that would help to maintain a large menu items on a pure static web site?

Comment: Check out http://hammerformac.com or http://incident57.com/codekit/

Comment: Thanks but these two seem to work only on MAC.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just tried to figure this out recently, although I ended up using PHP. If you want to use PHP, here is the following snippet I used:

Create a function

```
            <?php

        function echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri) {
            $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

            if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
                echo 'class="active"';
        }

        ?>
```

Then, add these to your `<li>` tags:

```
<li <?php echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("about-us")?>>
                    <a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
```

Hope this helps. I'll try to give credit if I can find the link where I found this solution.